# Java Detecting Oracle Database Down Error Codes

Tags: java, oracle, sqlexception, error-code

I want to detect when a Oracle database is down. These below error codes are taken from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/pagehelp/JDBCjdbcdatasourcesjdbcdatasourceconfigconnectionpooltitle.html:

■
3113: "end-of-file on communication channel"

■
3114: "not connected to ORACLE"

■
1033: "ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress"

■
1034: "ORACLE not available"

■
1089: "immediate shutdown in progress - no operations are permitted"

■
1090: "shutdown in progress - connection is not permitted"

■
17002: "I/O exception"

I would like to detect without using DataSource resource injection without a Glassfish server when the Oracle database is down. Below is the sample code:

```
public class Database {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {
             Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "username", "password");
             Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
             ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(new String("SELECT name FROM NAMES");
         }
         catch(SQLException e) {
             // use the error code defined above to detect database is down
         }
    }
 }
```

As this is a standlone application, can these error codes be used and will they work or are there some other error codes that work for standlone applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those codes are related to (and returned by) the JDBC driver and should work regardless of *where* the JDBC driver is deployed (whether it's a standalone app or an app server).